# White smoke is coming from my engine. how do i find out what it is?

Tags: engine, exhaust, radiator, hose, smoke

I own a 92 chevy lumina, when i drive or let it run for a little bit it will smoke from underneath the upper radiator hose. it is not the actual radiator hose as i changed it thinking it was that. There is no smoke coming from the exhaust as i checked that. Wanted to know if there was a way for me to troubleshoot what is wrong.

Comment: Could it be steam?

Comment: A new pope's been elected?

Answer (score 1):

- **Scenario 1:**

White smoke from the Engine bay usually means that either its your coolant or water evaporating ,basically steam.

You do not have to worry about it as its not a critical issue you can drive to a service stop, your radiator hose is probably blown and its an easy fix.

- **Scenario 2**

One of your gaskets is blown or about to blow, a way to surely pin point this issue is to smell the smoke, if it smells like rubber or something burning up then there is a high chance its one of your gaskets.

This is sort of critical and you need to take care of this asap. Identify which part is causing the smoke.